# How to catch an Exception in an Event-method

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

When I made a LostFocus-event for a TextBox, a `NotImplementedException()` is added. How do I catch this exception? My code is:

```
void marks_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Edited

I m sorry to be unclear the question that i wanted to ask is that when i create an event of lostFocus the VS automatically adds this line. Academically speaking. where can i catch this exception and what is use of it. why does the VS automatically adds this line

Comment: Where do you wish to catch this exception? Catch all unhandled exceptions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762526/how-can-i-make-something-that-catches-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-a-winforms-a

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it around [try/catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)?

```
void marks_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    try
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // handle ex
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the method which triggers the event can catch all unhandled exceptions that the subscriber methods throws. There is also a fallback solution which you can use:

Subscribe on the [Application.ThreadException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) event.

In Program.cs:

```
Application.ThreadException += OnThreadException


private static void OnThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you can implement this method.

But if you want to handle unhandled exceptions, you can try to use [unhandled exception event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) of your `AppDomain` or any other [global exception handler](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/0412ffc3-5065-4224-ac4f-b40660fd060b/)

Comment: The AppDomain event will still terminate the application

Comment: I assumed that most exceptions will be handled in local handlers and only critical ones would get to AppDomain (only for logging).

Answer (score 0):

Catching this exception from *within* the handler itself it nonsensical - managing it from calling code could make sense. However, it would seem you simply don't need it; given the context in which I see this, it serves precisely no purpose - you can prevent this exception by removing the code.

What you do in this block is implement your own logic. That is, you implement it.