# "Program has encountered an error" vs "Unhandled exception"

Tags: c#, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I have created a program that I have released online. I have tried to handle all the `exception`, but sometimes the program still has crashes. But when I reproduce the crash on my side, it says:
 "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application". 
The users of my program see "The program has encountered a problem" and a little bar comes up with text above it "Looking for solution".

Do I see a different window to the users because I have the full development environment installed and they just have the runtime? And is there a way to save the DEV state of the program when it crashes or bring up a message saying:
"The program has crashed, would you like to send details to the developer"
 or something like that?

Comment: can you confirm what technology you are using? by application is it WPF?  Have you looked at other questions, for instance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762526/how-can-i-make-something-that-catches-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-a-winforms-a

Comment: It sounds like they might not have the required .net runtime installed on their machine

Comment: It's written in C# with Visual Studio Express 2013 for Desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding event handlers to `Application.ThreadException` and `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` to implement general error handling there.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're developing for windows. The crash your users are seeing is different presumably because when you're running it you have a debugger attached.

What you could do is download the "Microsoft Ecosystem Metadata Exchange" (MEME) program from  https://sysdev.microsoft.com/, by logging in with your MSDN account, you should be able to find the download.

The "Looking for solution" dialog is sending minidumps to sysdev.

- register your binaries with the MEME tool
- check out sysdev site for your minidumps
- open minidump with visual studio and select your binary
- you're in debug mode broken at the exception.
- inspect call stack
- profit