# C# + MongoDB: Program terminates and throws no exceptions

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using MongoDB on C# and trying to do simple query.
Program execution terminates on lines like:

```
var people = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync();
```

or on line

```
using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter))
```

It trows no exceptions, it has Console.WriteLine("test") and Console.ReadLine()
at the end of the program which are not executed. In cmd I see that connection to DB is established.

Any ideas?

P.S.

```
 var filter = Builders<Follower>.Filter.Eq("id", f.id);
        List<Follower> fetchedFollowers = new List<Follower>();
        Console.WriteLine("0");
        try
        {
            using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("1");
                while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    var batch = cursor.Current;
                    foreach (Follower foll in batch)
                        fetchedFollowers.Add(foll);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Exception block");
            Console.WriteLine("2");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("3");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Update. This line:

```
 var count = await collection.Find(filter).CountAsync();
```

gives the same result - program terminates

Comment: How can you tell its terminating? Could it be waiting for something?

Comment: If it doesn't throw an exception, how do you figure it terminates? You could be hitting a deadlock for example.

Comment: The console closes without executingConsole.WriteLine("test") and Console.ReadLine(), I put try-catch everywhere, and I also went trough each line with breakpoints and it never entered any catch blocks, and studio's output says The thread 0x26bc has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Can you show the full code where you put a try and catch around the line that you think causes the program to terminate? and also include the `Console.Writeline` statements

Comment: @BenKnoble The console closes without executingConsole.WriteLine("test") and Console.ReadLine(), I put try-catch everywhere, and I also went trough each line with breakpoints and it never entered any catch blocks, and studio's output says The thread 0x26bc has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Comment: Chances are that mongo related code runs in its own thread so you won't catch it. You might try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762526/how-can-i-make-something-that-catches-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-a-winforms-a to handle uncaught exceptions - if program quits with an exception. You can also try ( in debugger) to stop on all exceptions being thrown (configuration option in Visual Studio).

Comment: @YacoubMassad I added code in the main post

Comment: @user3669608, so what you are saying is that you get "0" on the console, but then the program terminates before you get "1" or "Exception block" on the console, right?

Comment: Is there a synchronous version of the method your are trying to invoke? And if there is, do you get the same issue if you use it?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yes, exactly.

Comment: @YacoubMassad I am new to it and I haven't found synchonous method, but I was asking it here and it seems that im new mongo c# driver there are not

Comment: @user3669608, I think there is a synchronous version called [Find](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/Overload_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_Find.htm?_ga=1.100249176.756406971.1443981016). Please try it to see if it causes the same issue or if it throws a meaningfull exception.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Thanks. there is. can you help me please to move further? After I use people =  collection.Find(filter); I need to make "people" variable enumerable (as I see from errors in studio) to make it possible to go thrhrough it woth "foreach". How can I do it? Or, I only need to check if query has returned 0 values or not. Is there easy way after using find()?

Comment: I was using var people = await collection.Find(filter).ToListAsync(); before which had the same result. can I remove await from here? I actually dont need it

Comment: all I actually need is for this line to work:  var count = await collection.Find(filter).CountAsync(); and result is the same

Comment: @AnnaF can you show how you call that code from main?

Comment: Opened a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32966361/mongodb-c-sharp-2-0-1-driver-connection-suddenly-closes

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like improper use of `async` and `await`.  Note that `await` does not actually force the program to wait for the result (that is done with `Task.Wait()`). `await` just specifies what should be done when the asynchronous task completes.  If your program consists of a call to an asynchronous method and you never wait for the result, it will terminate before the asynchronous task completes.

Comment: Thank you! I really forgot to 'await' in Program.cs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  This is what worked for me:

```
        using (var cursor = collection.FindAsync(filter))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1");
            while (cursor.Result.MoveNext())
            {
                var batch = cursor.Result.Current;
                foreach (Follower foll in batch)
                    fetchedFollowers.Add(foll);
            }
        }
```