# MongoDB c# 2.0.1 driver- connection suddenly closes

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Here's the full program code:
(Except for Follower class which is only id and username - Json-type class)
I don't have any users for db - just created simple collection

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DBClass db = new DBClass();
        db.check();
    }
}

class DBClass
{
    protected string connectionString ="mongodb://localhost:27017";
    protected IMongoClient _client;
    protected IMongoDatabase _database;
    protected IMongoCollection<Follower> collection;

    public DBClass()
    {
        _client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        _database = _client.GetDatabase("FollowedUsers");
        collection = _database.GetCollection<Follower>("UserData");
    }

    public async void  check()
        {
        var filter = Builders<Follower>.Filter.Eq("id", "266663861");
        var result = await collection.Find(filter).CountAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

}

This is what I see in mongod:

```
2015-10-06T12:08:24.119+0300 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection
 accepted  from 127.0.0.1:50069 #2 (1 connection now open)
 2015-10-06T12:08:24.243+0300 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection
 27.0.0.1:50069 (0 connections now open)
```

when I run it from VS it just terminates, throws no exceptions, this is what I see in the output  The program '[11724] MongoTest.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
When I debug it I see that it terminates on this line:

```
var result = await collection.Find(filter).CountAsync();
```

Did I configure smth incorrectly?

Comment: 1. Change check to return a Task... async Task check().
2. From Main, do db.check().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

Comment: @CraigWilson it fails after timeout. What does this mean?

Comment: That probably means it couldn't talk to the server, but I don't have any stacktraces or exceptions to tell your for sure.

Comment: @CraigWilson That time mongod was not launched, and I tried to launch it and the program worked! Do I need to set up some kind of service to work without manually launching mongod? sorry for questions like this I am new to all of it (programming, dbs, work with shell etc)

Comment: You can set it up to run as a service: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to MongoDB.
Reason of problem is main thread closes mongoDb connection while dbCheck is being executed.

You should change next rows:
1)

> public async **Task** check()

2)

> db.check().**Wait()**;