# wpf crashes on another computer when I open a window with windowsformhost and reportviewer

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, rdlc

I have an app and it works on my computer just fine, but when I copy it to another laptop and I try to open a window with a windows forms host with a report viewer in the WinForms host, the app crashes.

My XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Zavod.Izvestaji.Izvestaj02"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:rv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms;assembly=Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Zavod.Izvestaji"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Завод за заштиту споменика културе у Панчеву" 
    Height="677.188" Width="837.317" 
    ResizeMode="CanMinimize" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    FontFamily="Verdana" 
    Background="#FFA38566">

    <Grid>

        <WindowsFormsHost Margin="0,84,0,0">
            <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="reportViewerObrazac02" 
                RenderingComplete="reportViewer_RenderingComplete" />
        </WindowsFormsHost>

        <TextBox x:Name="textBoxObjekat" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Height="23" Width="223"
            Margin="168,32,0,0" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top"  
            IsEnabled="False"/>

        <Button x:Name="buttonIzaberiObjekat" 
            Content="Изаберите објекат" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="396,34,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Click="buttonIzaberiObjekat_Click" />

        <Button x:Name="buttonIzvestaj" 
            Content="Генериши извештај" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Margin="548,34,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Click="buttonIzvestaj_Click" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In my code behind I don't have anything related to the WinForms host except an empty

```
private void reportViewer_RenderingComplete(object sender,
    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.RenderingCompleteEventArgs e)
{

}
```

These are my references:
[image]

Can someone help ?

Comment: I would say catch the exception or catch all unhandled exceptions and log the exception details so that you can see what is causing the crashes. There can be a lot of reasons on why your app crashes.

Maybe have a look at this post on how to catch all unhandled exceptions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762526/how-can-i-make-something-that-catches-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-a-winforms-a

Comment: have you installed reportviewer client?

Comment: you mean have I installed report viewer on the client machine also?not only on mine?

Comment: there is a redistributable viewer

Comment: just take care with the version you used

Comment: would this eliminate the exception "the invocation of the constructor on type microsoft reporting winforms reportviewer that matches the specified binding constraints" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you need to install Report Viewer Redistributable.

There are some different version, choose the version you need.

[Deploying Reports and ReportViewer Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251723.aspx)

[Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2008](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6576)

Comment: I need to instal this on a laptop? I mean,on every clint pc,that I put my app on?

Comment: Since I don't have an installer,I only copy my files from debug folder..I can use this redistributalbe instal,and it will work fine?