# How to open a new window in Windows Forms application using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, new-window, windows-10-desktop

I'm using a windows 10. In a Windows Forms application I'm trying to open a new window when I right click on the application icon from the task manager. Please refer the image:

[image]

As I'm a fresher I'm not getting any clue to implement this. Can anyone suggest me a way to open a new window in WindowsForms application.

Comment: If it helps, middle click should already do that for you by default. It opens a new instance of whatever you're clicking on.

Comment: But my application crashes when I click on the object. I'm getting the error as the WindowsForms application stopped working. Is there anything I should check for it?

Comment: @Arulpriya Find out why it crashed. Fix the problem. Since you can't attach the debugger, you'll need to [handle unhandled exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5762806/424129), and possibly add a lot of tracing to your program to identify where the problem is. Download [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx) to view debug trace output when VS isn't attached.