# .NET Generic Host : Prevent application crash on unhandled exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have a .NET Generic Host with an `IHostedService` that receives events from an OPC-UA interface and that process them.

The problem is that if an unhandled exception occurs during the processing of an event, the whole application crashes

I read the documentation but I didn't find anything about a global exception handler or a similar mechanism that allows to catch unhandled exception and prevent an application crash.

Is there a solution to protect the Generic Host, as well as the `IHostedService` against unhandled exceptions ?

EDIT

I know, here the simplest thing is to try/catch the exception and not let it bubble up. But I'd like to know if there is a similar mechanism like in WinForms / WPF, where you can catch such exceptions more globally and prevent a crash.

EDIT

This is a simplified version of the code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");
        return new HostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment(environmentName)
            .ConfigureLogging((hostContext, logging) =>
            {
                ...
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, builder) =>
            {
                builder
                    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", true, true)
                    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{hostContext.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName}.json", true, true)
                    .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, OpcClientHostedService>();
                ...
            });
    }
}

public class OpcClientHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly OpcConfiguration _opcConfiguration;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly OpcClient _opcClient;

    public OpcClientHostedService(OpcConfiguration opcConfiguration, ILogger<OpcClientHostedService> logger)
    {
        _opcConfiguration = opcConfiguration;
        _logger = logger;
        _opcClient = new OpcClient(opcConfiguration.ServerUri);
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Connecting to OPC server with URI '{0}'", _opcConfiguration.ServerUri);
        try
        {
            _opcClient.Connect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogCritical(ex, "Cannot connect to OPC server");
            throw;
        }
        _logger.LogInformation("Connection to OPC server is successful");

        CreateOpcObservable().Subscribe(async args => await ProcessOpcEvent(args));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task ProcessOpcEvent(OpcValueChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        await MethodThatCanThrowAnException(args); // If the exception is not handled, the whole application crashes!
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Disconnecting to OPC server");
        _opcClient.Disconnect();
        _logger.LogInformation("Disconnection to OPC server is successful");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    ...
}
```

In this example, it is easy to add a try/catch block in the `ProcessOpcEvent` method, but it would be great to have a mechanism to avoid complete application crash in this kind of situation.

Comment: You may want to look at this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762526/how-can-i-make-something-that-catches-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-a-winforms-a)

Comment: show some code.  otherwise you're going to get theoretical statements.

Comment: @RyanWilson unfortunately this post is not helpful as my application is not a WinForms application, but a .Net core console application

Comment: What does the code look like?

Comment: @davidfowl I added some simplified code, but I think it contains all relevant parts

Comment: You could create an abstract class implementing `IHostedService` and have your services extend from that class instead of implementing the interface directly. Write your error handling in the abstract class, and provide a virtual / abstract method for your sub classes to implement instead of the normal `StartAsync`, etc.

Comment: Also, why are you subscribing to `CreateOpcObservable()` and then throwing away the subscription/disposable? It seems like you should keep the subscription around so you can dispose of it if/when necessary.

Comment: @cwharris in the real code I keep the reference

Comment: @sroll I don't understand what that means or how it applies to my suggestion...

Comment: Yea you just need to try catch

Comment: *“[is there] a similar mechanism like in WinForms / WPF”* – Yes and no: Exceptions are automatically caught inside of the request pipeline, so your application stays alive even though individual requests may fail. But the exceptions that hit at the Program.cs level are those, that the application cannot recover from automatically. So you will have to handle those. If your background service fails, then how should the application possibly handle that? _You_ will have to make sure that the background service runs without issues (or if there are issues, it has to handle them internally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an app domain level event handler but you won't be able to control execution continuing in any specific manner.  In order to be able to control execution and how it handles exceptions you MUST implement try/catch statements when you process your OPC payload messages.

Comment: This is the answer I feared :(
Adding try/catch statements is not a big deal but it would be good to have some kind of safety net.

Comment: Try catch statements are simple

Answer (score 2):

You can provide custom *IHostBuilder* and *IHost* implementations that wrap the originals and catch errors.

See this [gist sample](https://gist.github.com/crystalgreen/568b5815d4a3efded5e2530145d3d538) that demonstrates the approach and that logs global errors.