# (AccessViolationException was unhandled) How do i implement HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, error-handling

I came across a problem that is the AccessViolationException was unhandled after i run my program for about a day long.

(More information: I am using Visual Studio 2010)

However, it does not state where this exception occurs, there were two options given to me which is "ok" and "continue". When i pressed ok, nothing happened so i pressed continue and the program stops debugging.

When i tried to find a solution, i understand that i can implement [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx#id0070035) to fix this problem. However, i have no clue where to start.

Do i simply include the codes below only? And where do i include these code?

```
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions] 
[SecurityCritical]
public static int Main() 
{ 
   try
     {
       // Catch any exceptions leaking out of the program CallMainProgramLoop(); 
     }
   catch (Exception e) 
       // We could be catching anything here 
     {
         // The exception we caught could have been a program error
        // or something much more serious. Regardless, we know that
        // something is not right. We'll just output the exception 
       // and exit with an error. We won't try to do any work when
       // the program or process is in an unknown state!

        System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message); 
        return 1; 
     } 

  return 0; 

}
```

Alternatively, i can also do this [legacyCorruptedStateExceptionsPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/legacycorruptedstateexceptionspolicy-element) but it says that i should input the required statement in the config file. Where can i find the config file?

Appreciate all the replies!

Comment: You said _"i run my program for about a day long"_ and then _"i pressed continue and the program stops debugging"_ - does it mean that you running you program within Visual Studio debugger for days?

Comment: @vasily.sib Yes, i am currently doing a project for a company and it requires to run the program for days. But this exception caused it to stop so i was told to fix it. I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762526/how-can-i-make-something-that-catches-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-a-winforms-a). Also, be aware that Visual Studio 2010 reached End-of-Life in 2015 (and will reach extended support end date in the next year).

Comment: @vasily.sib thank you so much for helping. I understand that i must implement the code as stated in the other post but do i just create the function thats all? Do i have to call it somewhere in my code? I am so sorry for asking redundant question because the program is running again so i cannot amend the codes. I just want to clarify first and once the exception comes again, i can just straight away change it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The actual answer for you question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5762526/how-can-i-make-something-that-catches-all-unhandled-exceptions-in-a-winforms-a) and I really shouldn't answer it again, but I want to show you some code sample and I don't want to write it in comment :)

In one of my projects from time to time there was an unpredictable exception. To catch it I write this code in `Program.cs`:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    // add UnhandledException handler
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionHandler;

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}

private static void UnhandledExceptionHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // prepare message for user
    var message = "There was an unknown exception while running <app_name>!";
    var exception = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;

    if (exception != null)
    {
        // change message if there was actual exception
        message = $"There was an {exception.GetType().Name} exception while running <app_name>! {exception.Message}";
        // adding inner exceptions messages
        var innerException = exception.InnerException;
        while (innerException != null)
        {
            message += $"\r\n-> {innerException.GetType().Name}: {innerException.Message}";
            innerException = innerException.InnerException;
        }
#if DEBUG
        // add tracing info
        message += $"\r\n\r\n{GetStackTrace(exception)}";
#endif
    }
    if (e.IsTerminating) message += "\r\n\r\n<app_name> will be closed.";

    // showing message to the user
    MessageBox.Show(message, "Unhandled Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
#if DEBUG
private static string GetStackTrace(Exception exception)
{
    var trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(exception, fNeedFileInfo: true);
    var frames = trace.GetFrames()
        .Select((f, i) => {
            var filename = f.GetFileName();
            var methodInfo = f.GetMethod();

            var frame = $"#{i} in the method {methodInfo.DeclaringType.FullName}.{methodInfo.Name}()";
            if (filename != null) frame += $" (source file: {System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filename)}@{f.GetFileLineNumber()}:{f.GetFileColumnNumber()})";

            return frame;
        });

    return $"Full stack trace ({trace.FrameCount} frames total):\r\n{string.Join("\r\n", frames)}";
}
#endif
```

Now, when unhandled exception occurring - there will be a message box, that shows full exception message (and inner exceptions messages). There was also a full stack trace for **Debug** build with method name, line number and source filename where exception occure.

## About HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions

You mention a `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` attribute in your comment. [The docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.exceptionservices.handleprocesscorruptedstateexceptionsattribute?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) clearly says that you shouldn't use it unless you absolutely sure that you need it.

> Corrupted process state exceptions are exceptions that indicate that
>   the state of a process has been corrupted. We **do not recommend**
>   executing your application in this state.
>
> By default, the common language runtime (CLR) does not deliver these
>   exceptions to managed code, and the `try/catch` blocks (and other
>   exception-handling clauses) are not invoked for them. **If you are
>   absolutely sure** that you want to maintain your handling of these
>   exceptions, you must apply the
>   `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute` attribute to the method
>   whose exception-handling clauses you want to execute. The CLR delivers
>   the corrupted process state exception to applicable exception clauses
>   only in methods that have both the
>   `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute` and
>   `SecurityCriticalAttribute attributes`.

Corrupted process state means that some really catastrophic things happens and it safer for your app to die right now. If you are still not scared enough, here is the `Main()` method from the example above with the `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions` attribute set:

```
[STAThread]
[HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions, SecurityCritical]
static void Main()
{
    try
    {
        // add UnhandledException handler
        // AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += UnhandledExceptionHandler;
        // * in this particular case is not quite useful to handle this exceptions,
        //   because you already wrap your entire application in a try/catch block

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle it somehow
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was asked by my manager to create a log file for tracking the error and you answer it before i do my research. Thank you so much will try it once my program start having error!

Comment: When i tried to input your code into a new file, it shows error on these line   message += $"\r\n-> {innerException.GetType().Name}: {innerException.Message}"; and  message = $"There was an {exception.GetType().Name} exception while running <app_name>! {exception.Message}"; but when i tried removing $ it works. Is it alright to remove it? I am so sorry for asking these questions.

Comment: I guess it's because VS 2010 can't handle string interpolation. Just replace it with normal `string.Format()`.

Comment: One more question, so sorry. If i were to try implementing the codes i stated above the HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions. Where should i input these code? Inside the Form1.cs or Program.cs?

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question! Appreciate it.

Comment: @HanAngeline check my update of this answer about `HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions`

Comment: Thank you so much. I was asking too much as its a project for submission. Really appreicate it. Will update the outcome soon. Thank you once again