# Why does Connection.Open cause a Winforms program to stop

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

I have made a simple console app to execute sql queries to an access database. I'm also just learning how to use classes ect so I decided to try and make the program as the function of a class. Here it is.

```
using System.Data.OleDb;


namespace table
{
    class Program
    {
        static public string query;
        static public string path;
        static public table table1 = new table();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter databse file location: ");
            path = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter query: ");
            query = Console.ReadLine();
            table1.SqlRead (query, path);
            for (int i = 0; i < table1.data.Count; i += 1)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j< table1.data[i].Length; j += 1)
                {
                    Console .WriteLine (table1.data[i][j]);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
    class table
    {
        List<string> tempDataList = new List<string>();
        public List<string[]> data = new List<string[]>(); // both dimensions zero-based
        public void SqlRead(string q, string p)
        {
            string connectionSting = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + p + "; User Id=admin;Password=;";
            using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionSting))
            {
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(q, connection);
                connection.Open();
                using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i += 1)
                        {
                            tempDataList.Add(reader[i].ToString());
                        }
                        string[] tempDataArray = tempDataList.ToArray();
                        tempDataList.Clear();
                        data.Add(tempDataArray);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
   
}
```

This console program works fine. Might not be the best solution but it does work. The next step I wanted to do was to get a form with some kind of UI. I have started with a button, a input box for the query, and I copied the class into the form code. When I tried to use table1 I was given 'Inconsistent accessibility'. I worked around that by making the table class public. The program runs, but the OleDb connection does not work. I had some trouble with the Provider in the connection string in the console version but I fixed that by downloading the access database engine and changing the provider to Microsoft.ACE.OleDB.12.0 . Made sure that was the same in the forms.
When the form runs, I can tell using breakpoints that it reaches the line connection.Open(), at which point debugging just stops. the form closes, everything ends with no explanation. I have done try catch on the line and no exception is thrown.

Its such a strange problem to me and i can't find anyone else with the same. The only differences I can think of between the two programs is that for the console I had stored my test database in the solution folder. And for the forms I was using the same one. So I made a copy of the database in the form solution folder- no change. The one other difference I notice is that the solution explorer for the console program lists Dependencies, Properties, Program.cs, database.accdb ; but the forms version lists Dependencies, database.accdb, Properties, Program.cs. Don't think that means anything but I have no idea what is going wrong.

Both programs in Vs2022. Targeting .net 7.0.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you see in the Output window in VS? What version of .NET are you targeting? Are you using "Just my code" and/or break-on-throw instead of break-when-unhandled? Have you set-up an `AppDomain.UnhandledException` **and** [`Application.ThreadException`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5762526/159145) (WinForms-specific) handlers?

Comment: Since the problem is with the WinForms code, why don't you post that instead of the Console code?

Comment: fwiw, this class will force you to build your sql in a way that is seriously flawed, leaving you open to sql injection issues. You need a way to pass parameter data separately from the sql command string.

Comment: @Dai It is using 'just my code' and break when unhandled. I have not set up either of those handlers. I will look into those. Also after experimenting a bit, I have tried copying the original console app to another app as well as following a tutorial for this kind of program and I keep on getting the stop on connection.open(). The only project I have that works is the original console project.

Answer (score 1):

There is a HUGE problem with the data class, in that it forces you to build code that is susceptible to sql injection issues. Additionally, it spends a lot of time and memory copying between the results and arrays that can be done more efficiently. Let me suggest a better pattern:

```
public static class DB
{
    private static string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=MyDB.accdb; User Id=admin;Password=;";

    // this is PRIVATE! Can't call it directly
    private IEnumerable<T> GetData(string sql, Action<OleDbParameterCollection> addParams, Func<IDataRecord, T> translate)
    {
        // Note the "using" statements here.
        // This means we don't have to call .Close() ourselves,
        //  and in fact even makes the code *safer*, so the connection
        //  is closed *even if an exception is thrown*. The original
        //  could leave connections hanging open in that situation.
        // It is also important to understand that, thanks to 
        // ADO.Net connection pooling, it really is better to
        // create a new connection object pretty much every time you
        // run a query.
        using var cn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        using var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, cn);

        if (addParams is object) addParams(cmd.Parameters);

        cn.Open();
        using var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            yield return translate(rdr);
        }
    }

    // Each query in the app is listed in its own method below, with strongly-typed arguments.
    
    // As an example, say you have an Employee class and table, and want to get all employees with a user-provided last name. That would look like this:
    public static IEnumerable<Employee> GetEmployeesByLastName(string LastName)
    {
         return GetData("SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE LastName = ?", 
              p => p.Add("?", OleDbType.VarWChar, 30).Value = LastName,
              r => new Employee() {
                 EmployeeID = r["EmployeeID"],
                 FirstName = r["FirstName"],
                 LastName = r["LastName"],
                 Salary = r["Salary"]
              });
    }

    // As an app grows, you might move the queries into 
    // separate `internal` classes that can still use 
    // the `GetData()` method, or even into their own 
    // class library project in Visual Studio
}
```

Comment: Do you think the inefficiency of my solution is causing the program to crash and that might be what is causing the issue? Injections are definitely an issue in my code but not a major issue for this, I'm only programming this for myself to practice and learn how OleDb works. Thanks for the improvements though.

Comment: Injection, along with authentication, are the two security practices that are too important to do wrong **even on practice/learning/proof-of-concept work**.