# Prevent Winform to crash on unhandled exception

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception, .net-4.5

I'm trying to catch unhandled exception this way :

```
static class Program
{
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Program.ThreadExceptionEventHandler);
            Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(Program.UnhandledExceptionEvent);

            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        public static void UnhandledExceptionEvent(Object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("UnhandledExceptionEvent", "UnhandledExceptionEvent");
        }

        public static void ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, "ThreadExceptionEventHandler");
        }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Execute method on a new thread
            new Thread(delegate()
            {
                //Do stuff ...
                throw new Exception("Some random unhandled exception");

            }).Start();

        }
```

The exception is caught by the UnhandledExceptionEventHandler, I can see the message box popping, but the application still crashes saying "Program has stopped working".

How do I keep the application runnning after an exceptions occurs ?

Comment: Normally you would surround your code block with a try - catch block.The exception would be specific to what might occur and if you're not sure just use the Exception class.

Comment: I believe the "stopped working" message has something to do with another error.

Comment: @Tejaswi Rana If I surround with a try-catch block then it isn't an unhadled exception anymore, it's handled, which obviously won't crash the application, but it's not my question.

Comment: @Xenolightning There is no such property, please see youself : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unhandledexceptioneventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Mauren I did a new project with just the code above, nothing else

Comment: @Michael Look at the last answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049063/unhandled-exception-in-winforms-application?rq=1

Comment: @Michael isn't there a case where `ThreadExceptionEventHandler` will receive a `null` `ThreadExceptionEventArgs`?

Comment: @Tejaswi Rana the first answer actually solves my issue. Please post this as an answer, I will mark it as the solution.

Comment: @Mauren ThreadExceptionEventHandler is not firing in this example

Comment: Why not just fix the problem that is causing the unhandled exception?

Comment: @Michael I don't think I should take credit for someone else's answer.. and that too on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Tejaswi Rana You are not stealing anyone's anwser, you are just answering another question. I think giving an answer in the comment section is a Stack Overflow "bad practice"

Comment: cool. I will add it then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5049063/unhandled-exception-in-winforms-application?rq=1) for information related to catching unhandled excpetions.